# Issue With Menu Dropdown

Tags: jquery

Main Menu - Navbar

```js
$(".Services").hover(function() {
  $(".Services-Dropdown").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
  $(".Services-Dropdown").fadeOut("slow");
});
$(".Solutions").hover(function() {
  $(".Services-Dropdown-1").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
  $(".Services-Dropdown-1").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menubar">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand clearfix" href="index.php"><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="assets/img/png/Final%20Logo.png"> </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right font-menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
          <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="Services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="Solutions">Solution</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="Newsfeed.php">News & Updates</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://ww4.autotask.net/ClientPortal/Login.aspx?ci=800377" target="_blank">Support</a>
          </li>
          <li style="border-right:0"><a href="#contactus">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mob-menu">
      <a href="index.php"> <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="assets/img/png/Final%20Logo.png" style="position: absolute"></a>
      <img id="mob-menu-icon" src="assets/img/svg/menu.svg" class="hidden-md menu intialmenu" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <div class="Services-Dropdown Services Menubar-Dropdown">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row" style="padding-top:3%;padding-bottom: 3%">
        <a href="Ecm.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img src="assets/img/svg/ecm.svg" style="width:30%" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Enterprise Content <br> Management</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="Digital.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img src="assets/img/svg/digital.svg" style="width:30%" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Digital Media <br>Marketing</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="Msp.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img src="assets/img/svg/msp.svg" style="width:30%" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Managed IT<br>Services</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="Bc&Dr.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <div class="row"><img src="assets/img/svg/bc.svg" style="width:30%" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">BC & <br>DR</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Services-Dropdown-1 Solutions Menubar-Dropdown">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row" style="padding-top:3%;padding-bottom: 3%">
        <a href="Systems-Integration.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img style="width:30%" src="assets/img/svg/si.svg" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Systems <br> Integration</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="It-security.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img style="width:30%" src="assets/img/svg/sa.svg" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">IT <br> Security</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="Storage.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img style="width:30%" src="assets/img/svg/cloud.svg" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Storage <br> Solutions</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="ecm.html">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="border-right:0.1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3)">
            <div class="row"><img style="width:30%" src="assets/img/svg/wire.svg" /></div>
            <div class="menu-item">Wireless<br> Solutions</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Since huge amount of styling is involved, I suggest you visit http://www.missancomputer.com/about-us.php and try hovering over `Services / Solutions` to see the problem .

Problem in brief: Once I hover over services, and move my mouse towards the `services` dropdown, it blinks and comes back. More like off and on. What went wrong in the JS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so it is the padding of the `li` that is causing the issue. You also need to look at consolidating your hover effect. Here is my suggestion for your application - add a data tag to your `li` and now you have one consolidated function that will handle all of your dropdowns if the HTML is done right. I try to be very specific with the jQuery selector so that you know it is selecting the `li` for the navbar

### HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav">
    <li data-dropdown="Services-Dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="Services">Services</a>
        <div class="Services-Dropdown Menubar-dropdown" style="display:none;">Dropdown</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#navbar .nav > li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    var $dropdown = "." + $(this).data('dropdown');
    $(dropdown).fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: var dropdown = "." + $(this).data('dropdown'); if im not wrong .

Comment: `<li data-dropdown="Services-Dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="Services">Services</a>
        <div class="Services-Dropdown Menubar-dropdown" style="display:none;">Dropdown</div>
    </li>`

`$('#navbar .nav > li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    var dropdown = "." + $(this).data('dropdown');
    $(dropdown).fadeToggle("slow");
});`

Now what happens is both the drop downs gets triggered on hover over one of them .

Comment: Check it out in the same url .

Comment: and why does a lag happen when the animation is being applied . The FPS seems to be drastically reduced .